# Top 5 names from summed values depending on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in excel like this:
 
`A           B         C          D`
`Name      Num1       Num2       ID`
 `a          10         20         1`
 `a          20         40         1`
 `b          30         50         2`
 `b          50         10         1`
`a          10         40         2`
`b          20         30         1`
`...`
how can I find the top 5 names where ID=1 with highest SUM of Num1 and Num2.
What I would like to show is something like this:
`No.      TopName    TotalSum`
`1.          b         110`
`2.          a         90`
..and so on 
I know how to sum all of the numbers where ID=1 with this formula `SUMIF(D$2:D$1048576,1,B$2:C$1048576)`, but can't figure out how to find the highest nums, sum them and find the name... 
Note that I have 200k+ rows of data.

Comment: What you are looking for is group wise sum ranked. Do you have to use formula necessarily? If not you can look for solutions using Pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with formulas in 2 steps:

### Step 1

Prepare a set of results where you effectively apply a filter per the ID column:

```
F       | G         | H
Name-Id | Num1+Num2 | Rank
a1      | 150       | 5
b1      | 190       | 2
c1      | 140       | 6
d1      | 110       | 10
e1      | 120       | 8
f1      | 120       | 9
g1      | 140       | 7
h1      | 160       | 4
i1      | 180       | 3
j1      | 200       | 1
```

Where `Name-Id` is the concatenation of the unique values in column A plus the value from column D that you want to test for. I faked up some more data on top of your original example for `c` to `j`.

`Num1+Num2` is calculated by:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$33+$C$2:$C$33,--($A$2:$A$33=LEFT($F2,1)),--($D$2:$D$33=VALUE(RIGHT($F2,1))))
```

That is:

- `Num1` range plus `Num2` range which is the sum you want to rank
- Multipled by an array of 0s and 1s per the left-hand character of column F: `Name-Id` matching column A: `Name`
- Multipled by an array of 0s and 1s per the right-hand character of column F: `Name-Id` matching column D `ID`

And `Rank` is calculated by:

```
=RANK(G2,$G$2:$G$11,0)+COUNTIF($G$2:G2,G2)-1
```

Which is [a way](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2512-excel-unique-rank.html) to convert the output of `RANK` to give unique rank values.

### Step 2

Build a 'leader board' by doing an `INDEX` and `MATCH` look-up into `Name-Id` based on `Rank` - and then get the left-hand character from `Name-Id`. For `TotalSum` just do another similar `INDEX` and `MATCH` to get the score.

```
J    | K    | L
Rank | Name | TotalSum
1    | j    | 200
2    | b    | 190 
3    | i    | 180
4    | h    | 160
5    | a    | 150
```

Where the formula in column K is:

```
=LEFT(INDEX($F$2:$F$11,MATCH(J2,$H$2:$H$11,0)),1)
```

And the formula in column L is:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$11,MATCH(J2,$H$2:$H$11,0))
```

### Example

[image]

### Edit

Given the OPs large data-set (200k+ rows) you may want to automate the construction of the table with `Name-Id`, `Num1+Num2` and `Rank`. The method below does this but leaves blanks in the table. That doesn't prevent the construction of the 'leader board' section though.

Using the standard method to look for first instance of a value in a range (sorted or unsorted):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$3:A3,A3)=1,A3,"")
```

We can extend to concatenate the `ID` into this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$3:A3,A3)=1,A3&$G$1,"")
```

See the screenshot below where `ID` is now a parameter in `G1` - could be anywhere in the workbook though.

Now having this column automatically populated, we can adjust the `SUMPRODUCT`- and `RANK`-based formulas to be wrapped by an `IF` statement that checks that the the `Name-Id` is not blank:

`SUMPRODUCT` formula:

```
=IF($F3<>"",SUMPRODUCT($B$3:$B$34+$C$3:$C$34,--($A$3:$A$34=LEFT($F3,1)),--($D$3:$D$34=VALUE(RIGHT($F3,1)))),"")
```

`RANK` formula:

```
=IF(G3<>"",RANK(G3,$G$3:$G$34,0)+COUNTIF($G$3:G3,G3)-1,"")
```

The leader board formulas stay the same except they need to cover the new extended ranges of `Name-Id`, `Num1+Num2` and `Rank` rather than the hard-coded range in the previous example.

Updated screenshot noting the new `COUNTIF` formula concatenated with the `ID` to auto-generate the `Name-Id` pair column:

[image]

HTH

Comment: So far so good, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the Name-Id table without doubles or blanks, 0, False results and so on... I am busting my head all morning trying to figure it out... so far I came up with this: `=IF($D2=1,IF(A1=A2,,CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$33,$D2)))` Anything you could suggest?

Comment: I did hard-code in the Name-Id values - but it is possible to automate the construction of the Name-Id table but I only know how to do it with blank rows. The leader board table does not have blanks though - do you want me to edit that into the answer?

Comment: Post it, let's see what you got :) I also did a hard-code, but like I said, I have 200k+ rows of data, so a hard-code isn't possible...

Comment: @dnisko - have a look at the edit - hope it works for you. I don't know how to build the `Name-Id` with just formulas - probably would start looking at a VBA solution for that. Cheers.

Comment: Meant to say don't know how to build the `Name-Id` with ***no blanks*** with just formulas...

Comment: Also - maybe you can look at a SQL database solution as this stuff would be much easier with a SQL query.

Comment: I know that with SQL database and SQL query is much, much easier, but this is a specific problem where excel is the only tool available for use... Anyway, the main focus was the RANK (Ladder) table, so this is an acceptable answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be used Pivot Table

[image]

Comment: I would really like to avoid pivot tables... sorry I didn't mentioned that... I know it is easier, but I would like to try with formulas first. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the highest value the simple one is Max (B2 :B20).

If you want to find name carries highest value then, 
=Vlookup (Max (B2 :B20), A2:D20, 1,False).

If you want top Names considering values, 
=Large (B2 :B20, Row(1:5))

Drag to 5 rows.

NB it's an Array formula.

If you want to Sum top 5 values,,

=Sum(Large (B2 :B20, {1,2,3,4,5}))

NB it's also Array formula.